# A Windows 10 service is using ports 80 and 443. How can I change them?

Tags: windows-10, apache-http-server, firewall, port, netsh

I want to use ports 80 and 443 for Apache server but they are reserved for a windows service as shown by `netsh http show urlacl` 
[see output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXRJa.png)

Firewall inbound rules show that **BranchCache Hosted Cache Server** is using ports 80 and 443 [see screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WP8yy.png)

I managed to change the port for BranchCache Content Retrieval from port 80 using this [powershell script](http://code.avalon-zone.be/distributed-branchcache-change-default-tcp-port/)

I do not want to change the ports for Apache. How can I change the port for BranchCache Hosted Cache Server?

Answer (score 0):

[BranchCache](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/branchcache/branchcache)
technology is used more for a network file server than for a client system such
as Windows 10.

It is [defined](https://web.archive.org/web/20210115150052/http://geekswithblogs.net/Wchrabaszcz/archive/2015/07/01/server-2016--how-to-add-or-remove-windows-features.aspx) as:

> BranchCache for Network Files provides support for BranchCache on this file server. BranchCache is a wide area network (WAN) bandwidth optimization technology that caches content from your main office content servers at branch office locations, allowing client computers at branch offices to access the content locally rather than over the WAN.

In a standard Windows 10 configuration, I would say that it is not required.

To disable it
([link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-essentials/manage/manage-branchcache-in-windows-server-essentials#use-windows-powershell-to-turn-branchcache-on-or-off)),
run PowerShell as Administrator and enter the following command:

```
Disable-WSSBranchCache
```

Comment: ```Disable-WSSBranchCache : The term 'Disable-WSSBranchCache' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script...```

Comment: How did you install BranchCache?

Comment: The powershell cmd: ```get-bcstatus``` shows that BranchCache is disabled

Comment: BranchCache came installed with windows 10. Although disabled, it has reserved ports 80 and 443

Comment: It comes with Windows but is normally inactive and doesn't use any ports. Start the Services applet and see if the BranchCache service is running. In any case, you may double-click its entry and set Startup type to Disabled, just to be sure. It should then not present any difficulty for Apache. You also need to assure that IIS is not enabled in "Turn Windows features on or off".

Comment: IIS is disabled and I have changed the startup type for BranchCache from manual to disabled but Apache isn't repsonding. ```netsh http show urlacl``` still shows that the ports are reserved

Comment: Reserved by what, is the question. Try using `netstat -ano | findstr :80` to identify the listening process.

Comment: ```UDP    [fe80::11b0:b5ba:17a7:8083%17]:1900  *:*                                    5744```
and 

  ```UDP    [fe80::11b0:b5ba:17a7:8083%17]:65106  *:*                                    5744```

Comment: Firewall inbound rules clearly show it branch cache using the ports

Comment: In Task Manager, which process-id is  5744?

Comment: I'm having the same issue and this does not solve it